# my code says lol is not a palindrome, why?

Tags: c++, palindrome

I was trying to do that simple code so i can practice c++, but I end up getting crazy because of my own code, the objective is to see if a string is a palindrome or not. Here it is. The problem I got is when I write "lol", it says: "is not a palindrome".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    system("Color 0A");
    string word;
    bool is_string;
    int a = 0;
    int points;
    
    cout << "write a word and see if it is a palindrome" << endl;
    cin >> word;
    for (int i = word.length(); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (word[i] != word[a])
        {
            is_string = false;
            cout << "is not a palindrome";
            i = 0;
        }
        if (word[i] == word[a])
        {
            points++;
        }
        a++;
    }
    if (points == word.length())
    {
        is_string = true;
        cout << "is a palindrome";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: in for loop replace `i = word.length()` with `i = word.length()-1` and initialize points with 0

Comment: __Debugging tip:__ After `cout << "is not a palindrome";` add `cout << " because word[" << i << "] != word[" << a <<"]\n";` and `cout << "I.e. '" << word[i] << "' != '" << word[a] << "'\n";`. This will let you see the values of your variables and zoom in on the logical flaw.

Answer (score 2):

Because string indexes start with 0 instead of 1, the last character's index will be 1 less than what you would expect. Replace `word.length()` with `word.length() - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a property in all codes, the first letter has the index '0' and the length of anything has the real length of the world, it means that for the word "lol", the "l" would have the index '0', the "o" the index '1' and the "l" the index '2', by trying to compare the letter with the index '3', you are trying to compare the word with and empty letter, so it couldn't works.
So to fix it you have 2 solutions

1. Replace everywhere the `i` by `i+1` it means replacing `word[i]` by `word[i+1]`
2. Replace `for (int i = word.length(); i >= 0; i--)` by `for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: It's not a property of all programming languages that indices start with 0. Just most of them. Also, I don't think solution #1 would work properly.

Comment: Thought it was so because I saw it also in python, solution #1 would work because it's putting an offset on the `i` variable

Comment: Replacing `i` by `i+1` **everywhere** certainly will not work. Just look at what happened to the initialization `int i+1 = word.length()`. Even if you meant replacing just `word[i]`, the expression `word[i+1]` is not going to work out well when `i` is `word.length()` as you just pushed the code into undefined behavior. (Did you mean `i-1` instead?)

Comment: *"It's a property in all codes, the first letter has the index '0'"* -- This is not true for Basic and Pascal code (and others, but these are the first two I thought of).